# Ionic app goes to background and restarts unexpectedly

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, crash

My Ionic app crashes (?) unexpectedly. What is really happening is that while the application is running, the application goes to the background unexpectedly and when I tap to open it again, it is like it is starting from the beginning.

This usually happens when the application is open for a lot of time (like 2 or 3 hours), but not always.

- I have checked about memory issues, no subscriptions are forgotten to
  unsubscribe.
- I have tried to inspect the application via USB to my machine so
  maybe I could see an error message when the crash happens, but no
  error message appeared.
- I also read [this article](https://techbeacon.com/app-dev-testing/top-6-reasons-mobile-apps-crash-how-best-avoid-murphy), but I believe none of the issues apply
  to my problem.

I would appreciate any recommended tools for debugging application
crashes (if any), as well as any other ideas why such case could
happen.

I know that my question is a little bit general, but it is the nature of the issue that makes it like that.

Here are the plugins I am using

```
"cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "^1.1.0",
"cordova-plugin-ble-central": "^1.2.5",
"cordova-plugin-bluetoothle": "^4.5.14",
"cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^3.2.0",
"cordova-plugin-insomnia": "^4.3.0",
"cordova-android": "^9.1.0",
"cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "^3.1.0",
"cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
"cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.1.0",
"cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
"cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.2.1",
"cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": "^2.3.0",
"cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.4",
"cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
"cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
```

Comment: You can see logs in Android Studio. what plugins are you using? check if any of the plugin causing this issue.

Comment: i would either make little steps with LogCat in Android, or using Breakpoints to monitor current behaviour until some points. Maybe you can narrow the error to a specific point?

Comment: Thanks for your effort guys, I will try to connect with android studio and give feedback. I also updated my question by referencing the plugins I am using.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to install [Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/products/crashlytics) and see what kind of errors are closing your app. There is also a plugin for it [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-crashlytics) but I recommend to install it manually.